# What approaches does WinRT support for federated authentication?

Tags: windows-runtime, federated-identity

I'm trying to write a Windows Store App that supports integration with a federated identity provider, such as ADFS or Windows Azure AD Access Control.

What approaches for federated auth and access-control does WinRT support and what classes/libraries should be leveraged?